# Search Result Web Part Not Displaying Any Results when Ranked Results Disabled

Tags: search, search-results, sharepoint-on-prem

I've added a Search Results Web Part to a SP2013 page where users would like to be able to search the contents of the posts. I've configured the Search Results Web Part to 'Items matching a content type' from the 'current site', not restricted by any tag, and restricted by 'post' content type. There are 42 total results on the page and when the ranked results is enabled, the first ten appear on the Search Results web part. I'm also able to enter a keyword in the search box web part and pull up any of the 42 results in the Search Results Web Part successfully.

However, when I disable the ranked results (I don't want users to see results before they've entered a keyword) and search for one of the keywords I get 'Nothing here matches your search'. Any insight on why this is happening and a workaround would be extremely helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the Ranked Results table are your results. In other words, by removing the Ranked Results you are eliminating the content you are trying to show. If you don't want the part to load before the query wrap the whole query like this: `{? your query }` SO if your query is `{searchboxQuery} Content Type:Post` make it {? `{searchboxQuery} Content Type:Post}`

Comment: Thanks Matthew, that did the trick. I was still having an issue after wrapping my query since the results would show 'Nothing here matches your search' but I implemented a change to the Display Settings Template, explained here, and that solved the problem. Thanks to you and Prasad Pathak for your assistance!